# Add a series of values into a file using awk or sed

Tags: shell, awk

I want to insert a column the following file using awk. File structure:

`1.05228541071
 1.04732408695
 1.04255736847
 1.03783173687
 1.03314654421
 1.02850114709
...`

I was using the following command to add a column (from 0 days).

`awk '{print x+0, $1; x+=73}' file >file_vs_days`

And I get the following result for each row:

file_vs_days:

`0 1.05228541071
73 1.04732408695
146 1.04255736847
219 1.03783173687
292 1.03314654421
365 1.02850114709
...`

My problem is in the next row (7th), I want it to start at 365 instead of 365 + 73.

For example:

```
0 1.05228541071
73 1.04732408695
146 1.04255736847
219 1.03783173687
292 1.03314654421
365 1.02850114709
365 x7 
(365+1*73) x8
(365+2*73) x9
(365+3*73) x10
(365+4*73) x11
(365+5*73) x12
...
```

How can I modify the command to print the values every 6 rows?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the first column based on `NR` (line number):

```
awk '{print ((NR-1)%6*73), $0}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This awk one-liner should help you:

```
awk '{s=73*x++;x=x==6?0:x;print s, $0}' file
```

If we do a little test:

```
kent$  awk '{s=73*x++;x=x==6?0:x;print s" - " $0}' <(seq 21) 
0 - 1
73 - 2
146 - 3
219 - 4
292 - 5
365 - 6
0 - 7
73 - 8
146 - 9
219 - 10
292 - 11
365 - 12
0 - 13
73 - 14
146 - 15
219 - 16
292 - 17
365 - 18
0 - 19
73 - 20
146 - 21
```